# Accessing results from my first SOQL search

Tags: trigger, email, compile-error

My Trigger will send an email anytime one account has 7 cases created within 8 days. Towards the bottom in my Else block, I am trying to access fields in my first SOQL statement. I have tried many ways and read many help pages. Help with the syntax for the line: message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + cl.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)cl.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';`

is greatly appreciated.

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                         FROM Case
                                         WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:8
                                         GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                         HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 7];

                         Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();
                for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){

                    Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
                        AcctIds.add(accId);
                }

                List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c, 
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c    
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            for(Case cl:caseList){ 

                if(cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project'){    
                        //Private method *** getAddresses() *** retrieves email address from Customer_Success_Managers Public Group
                             message.toAddresses  = getAddresses();   
                        }
                        else{  
                             message.toAddresses = new String[] { Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c  };

                        }
                    message.Subject = 'Subject Test Message';
                    message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + cl.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)cl.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            }
private List<String> getAddresses(){
List<User> UserList =
        [SELECT id, name, email
        FROM User 
        WHERE id 
        IN (SELECT userorgroupid 
            FROM groupmember
            WHERE group.name = 'Customer Success Managers')];

List<String> emailString = new List<String>();

for(User u: UserList){
    emailstring.add(u.email);
}   
return (emailString);
}
```

Comment: What do you want from the aggregateResultList to put into the message specifically?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "having issues". If you get an error message, please **[edit]** your post to include it ***verbatim***.

Comment: Line: 33, Column: 1
System.SObjectException: Invalid field name for Case

Comment: Please stop creating new versions of the question and instead **[edit] *this one***.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line

```
message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + cl.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)cl.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
```

Specifically:

```
cl is defined of type Case

cl.get('name') // no such field Name on Case.
```

Consult your [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm?search_text=case) for valid OOTB field names. Case happens to be one of the Sobjects that does not have a `Name` field. Instead, there's `CaseNumber`

Furthermore, you never retrieve `Name`, even if you could, in your SOQL.

Comment: In order to access the 'Name' field on the Account object, what does that syntax look like?  I've tried using the Relational name in the manner:

`message.toAddresses = cl.get('Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c');`

Error message:
`Line: 29, Column: 34
Illegal assignment from Object to List<String>
`

Comment: Case object has a Lookup relationship to the custom object `Parent_Project_if_applicable__c`

Comment: you can't use the `get` method to traverse relationships; use `cl.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c`

Comment: Thank you.  When I use the line `else{  
                                 message.toAddresses = cl.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c;   
                            }` . I receive the error message 
`Line: 29, Column: 34
Illegal assignment from String to List<String>
`

Comment: that's because `message.toAddresses` is a list and you are trying to assign a singleton to it; you need to assign a list to it.

Answer (score -2):

I found that instead of attempting to access the variable from the SOQL search, I would just place them in a String that is accessible by the If/Then Statement.  I created `List<String> ListOfMessages = new List<String>();` and pushed each line in to List.

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                         FROM Case
                                         WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:2
                                         GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                         HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 2];
         String messageToSend;
         List<String> ListOfMessages = new List<String>();
         Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){
        String messageToSend = 'Account name: ' + aggr.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)aggr.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
        //ListOfMessages.add(messageToSend);

        Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
        AcctIds.add(accId);
    }

List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                       Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c, 
                       Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c,
                       Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c
                       FROM Case
                       WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

for(Case cl:caseList){ 
     //I can now access those fields through a String Variable, much easier.
     System.debug('in the loop: ' + messageToSend);
```

}

Comment: This code's not correct as shown. It does not collect a `List<String>`. Even if it did, it's not clear that a `List<String>` is the right data structure - a `Map<Id, String>` is probably required to correlate messages back to Account Ids.